# Recyclerview data disappears when device is rotated

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, activity-lifecycle

Even though I am using ViewModel, whenever the device is rotated, the data in the Recyclerview disappears. I had to put the makeSearch() method inside the onClick() method because I need to get the text that the button grabs and use it as the search parameter. Is there a better way I can handle this to avoid this problem? My code is right here:

SearchActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

// What happens when the search button is clicked
materialButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(textInputEditText.getText()).toString().isEmpty()) {
             textInputEditText.setError("Type a search query");
            } else {
                mSearchInput = Objects.requireNonNull(textInputEditText.getText()).toString();
                textInputEditText.setText("");
                makeSearch();
            }
        }
    });
}

// Gets the ViewModel, Observes the Question LiveData and delivers it to the Recyclerview
private void makeSearch() {
    final SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter();
    SearchViewModel mSearchViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
            new CustomSearchViewModelFactory(new SearchRepository())).get(SearchViewModel.class);
    mSearchViewModel.setQuery(mSearchInput);
    mSearchViewModel.getQuestionLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Question>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Question> questions) {
                    mQuestions = questions;
                    searchAdapter.setQuestions(questions);
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        searchAdapter.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
}
```

SearchViewModel:

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {

private SearchRepository mSearchRepository;
private MutableLiveData<String> mSearchLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LiveData<List<Question>> mQuestionLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(mSearchLiveData, (query) -> {
    return mSearchRepository.getQuestions(query);
});

SearchViewModel(SearchRepository searchRepository) {
    this.mSearchRepository = searchRepository;
}

public LiveData<List<Question>> getQuestionLiveData() {
    return mQuestionLiveData;
}

public void setQuery(String query) {
    mSearchLiveData.setValue(query);
}
}
```

SearchRepository:

```
public class SearchRepository {

//private String inTitle;
private MutableLiveData<List<Question>> mQuestions = new MutableLiveData<>();

public SearchRepository() {
    //getQuestionsWithTextInTitle();
}

private void getQuestionsWithTextInTitle(String inTitle) {
    ApiService apiService = RestApiClient.getApiService(ApiService.class);
    Call<QuestionsResponse> call = apiService.getQuestionsWithTextInTitle(inTitle);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<QuestionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<QuestionsResponse> call, Response<QuestionsResponse> response) {
            QuestionsResponse questionsResponse = response.body();
            if (questionsResponse != null) {
                mQuestions.postValue(questionsResponse.getItems());
                //shouldShowData = true;
            } else {
                Log.d("SearchRepository", "No matching question");
                //shouldShowData = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<QuestionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            //shouldShowData = false;
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public LiveData<List<Question>> getQuestions(String inTitle) {
    getQuestionsWithTextInTitle(inTitle);
    return mQuestions;
}
}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything in `onCreate()` to repopulate your `RecyclerView`, from what I can see. You are limiting yourself a lot by saying that `inTitle` needs to be a constructor parameter of your viewmodel, since that value will change as the user types in searches. You might want to have your viewmodel expose a stable `LiveData` (e.g., a `MediatorLiveData`) that the activity can always observe, and have searches update that stable output. See https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/Weather for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of passing the search input in through your `CustomSearchViewModelFactory` and into the constructor for the ViewModel and into the constructor for your `SearchRepository` isn't going to work in any case. While the first time you search your `CustomSearchViewModelFactory` creates the ViewModel, the second time you hit search, your `SearchViewModel` is already created and your factory is not invoked a second time, meaning you never get the second query.

Instead, you should file the [ViewModel Overview documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata), and use `Transformations.switchMap()` to convert your input (the search string) into a new `LiveData<List<Question>>` for that given query.

This means that your ViewModel would look something like

```
public class SearchViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private SearchRepository mSearchRepository;
    private MutableLiveData<String> mSearchLiveData = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    private LiveData<List<Question>> mQuestionLiveData =
        Transformations.switchMap(mSearchLiveData, (query) -> {
            return mSearchRepository.getQuestions(query);
         });

    public SearchViewModel() {
        mSearchRepository = new SearchRepository();
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        mSearchLiveData.setValue(query);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Question>> getQuestionLiveData() {
        return mQuestionLiveData;
    }
}
```

You'd then update your Activity to:

1. Always observe the `getQuestionLiveData()` (note that you won't get a callback to your Observer until you actually set the first query)
2. Call `setQuery()` on your `SearchViewModel` in your `makeSearch()`
3. Remove your `CustomSearchViewModelFactory` entirely (it would no longer be needed).

Comment: Hi @ianhanniballake, thanks for your response. I'm having a challenge with a portion of the code you wrote. First of all, `mQuestionLiveData` is a `LiveData<List<Question>>` not `LiveData<String>`. Secondly, `mSearchRepository.getQuestions()` returns a `LiveData<List<Question>>` as you can see in my `SearchRepository` class I added above. This has made it a bit challenging to implement the code you wrote, please help

Comment: @MayorJay - yes, you're right. I've corrected my code

Comment: the correction still didn't help solve my problem. Please check through my `SearchRepository` class above. Thanks. When I tried your code I got this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.josycom.flowoverstack.viewmodel.SearchViewModel`

Comment: You need to change your SearchRepository as well so that it doesn't take a constructor parameter, but instead takes that input to getQuestions(), building a new LiveData instance for each query

Comment: I modified my code using your answer and examples I saw in the [ViewModel documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata), I passed the `SearchRespository` as a parameter to the `SearchViewModel` constructor. It worked in the sense that each time I type in a new search query, a new corresponding result is returned and displayed but on rotation of the device, the displayed data still disappears

Comment: Are you calling `observe()` in `onCreate()`? Please edit your with your updated code.

Comment: I have my updated code up here now. Kindly check through

Comment: It doesn't look like you did any of the points in my answer - you didn't move your `observe()` to `onCreate()` to always call it like I said in point #1, you didn't update `makeSearch()` to only call `setQuery()` on your ViewModel like I said in point #2, nor did you copy the `SearchViewModel` I provided which unconditionally created the `SearchRepository` internally rather than use it as a constructor parameter, which would have allowed you to do point #3.

Comment: I have updated my code in line with the points you made, it works perfectly now. Thank you so much